# How to make the texture in sliced mode?

Tags: opengl, textures, jogl

I have a `GL.GL_QUAD_STRIP` with a texture , since the `GL.GL_QUAD_STRIP` sizes are much larger then the texture image sizes , this image become stretched and blur  , So I thought maybe there is a way to set this texture in "sliced" mode to make it more clearly and sharp .

**Edit:**  "sliced" I mean in the location the images end I would be start to be drawn again except to be appear one whit hard stretch .

That's what I have so far -

```
double m_x , m_y  , m_z ; 
Texture m_cubeSides ; 

public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)
{
        final GL gl = gLDrawable.getGL();
        gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        m_cubeSides.bind();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUAD_STRIP);

        // Quad 1

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, m_y, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, 0, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, m_y, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);

        // Quad 2 - front 

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, m_y, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, m_y, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, 0, m_z);

        //  Quad 3 - east side 

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, m_y, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, 0, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, m_y, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(m_x, 0, 0);

        //  Quad 4 - west side 

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, m_y, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, m_y, m_z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, m_z);

        gl.glEnd(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by sliced mode, however changing the texture coordinates would work. There are an awful lot of calls to `glTexCoord2f` so perhaps a variable to replace all the instances of `1.0f` in the `glTexCoord2f` calls and then vary that till you get a nice result. You've already set the texture wrap mode to repeat which is required.

Something like:

```
 float textureMax = 5.0f;
 ...
 gl.glTexCoord2f(textureMax , 0.0f);
 gl.glVertex3d(m_x, m_y, 0);
 gl.glTexCoord2f(textureMax ,textureMax );
 gl.glVertex3d(m_x, 0, 0);
 gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
 gl.glVertex3d(0, m_y, 0);
 gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, textureMax );
 gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
```

The downside of this though is that you need a texture you can tile, otherwise this may not look great.

Another option is a bigger texture, of course :)